# (web3.js) The method eth_compileSolidity does not exist/is not available

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, solc, compiler

I have tried to develop a javascript function with web3.js to compile a solidity contract. In html/javascript code, I have prepared the following.

**var contract_code = "pragma solidity ^0.4.....[omit the content here])";
var compiled_contract = web3.eth.compile.solidity(contract_code);**

By reference of google chrome broswser developer tools, I found the following error.

> web3.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: The method eth_compileSolidity does not
>   exist/is not available
>       at Object.InvalidResponse (web3.min.js:1)
>       at s.send (web3.min.js:2)
>       at Object.e [as solidity] (web3.min.js:2)
>       at deployContract ((index):53)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):114)

I checked again the Ubuntu 16.04 server and confirmed the installation of solc.

**ubuntu@ip:~/node$ which solc
/usr/bin/solc**

I have search on Internet and someone have suggested to add --solc on geth command. My Geth version is v1.6.0.

**geth --datadir ethfolder --solc /usr/bin/solc**

However, it shows the following error message.

> flag provided but not defined: -solc

I tried the eth.getCompilers() command.

> eth.getCompilers();
>
> Error: The method eth_getCompilers does not exist/is not available
>       at web3.js:3104:20
>       at web3.js:6191:15
>       at web3.js:5004:36
>       at :1:1

I tried admin.setSolc function which is mentioned in the official wiki.

> admin.setSolc('/usr/bin/solc');
>
> TypeError: 'setSolc' is not a function
>       at :1:1

Would anyone can advise hint on how to implement the compiling job on web3.js?

Comment: Thank you very much and I understand the story behind. I will try https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js instead of original compiler functions.